# Sqlite3 dbase table permanently locked for write

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

While running Python3 code in Jupiter Notebook, the code reads and writes from an sqlite3 db.  It has had an intermittent dbase locking problem that now seems to be permanent.  At the moment, the code can read from the dbase but cannot write to it.  The error is:

```
Execution failed on sql 'DROP TABLE "T2_xxx"': database table is locked
```

or

```
Execution failed on sql 'DROP TABLE "T2_xxx"': database is locked
```

I have been through all the relevant posts here on stack and can confirm:

- the problem is *not* another process accessing the db.  There are no other processes running other than OS and Jupyter notebook.
- copying the db file and moving/renaming/etc. does not help
- changing the 'timeout' does not correct the problem
- I *can* read the dbase with other apps.  I have used both Beaver.db and DB Browser for sqlite3 and can connect to and edit the dbase with either one (and yes after shutting those apps I can't access the db with my Jupyter scripts)
- I have rebooted repeatedly
- I have run Jupyter both with and without the Conda environment but this did not seem to be a factor.
- There are no connection problems and there is only one write statement:

```
T2_temp.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Additional interesting behaviours are:

- I can create a new table and write to it once.  Any further writes report that the table is locked.
- the Jupyter kernel has been regularly restarted during development

I would like to know if anyone knows why the locking can occur in the situation I explained and if it is possible to unlock the db.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but have you checked the access permissions on the DB file?  (read/write?)

Comment: Tnx but SQLite3 doesn't have access control and the environment (user/code environment/machine used) have not changed.  Also file owner is the user running the code so not an OS level problem either.

Comment: I added in the actual error message.